# Insert row in Clipper .DBF with .NTX

Tags: c#, dbf

I want to insert data from a old clipper program's database using c#

the database is associated with an .ntx file.

i can insert data using vfpoledb driver to the dbf in my c# program, however, when i look at the old clipper program, the data was not there but it is in the dbf.

the culprit was the .ntx file, it needed to be reindexed so the data would be visible in the clipper program. The reindexing was done by the old program when ever i delete the .ntx files.

how can i insert data and update the .ntx files as well? the old program was not made by me but a past employee here in the company.

Comment: Hi Ken, thanks for the fast response, btw i have no idea what advantage database is because im new to this product, where can i learn how to use this? i'm trying find the tutorial page, but i can't seem to find it

Comment: Hi Ken, Cheers! i have solve my problem using the product you have showed, the Advantage Database Server. It took me some time to understand how the server works, it seemed to work like a service enhancement wrapped to the old databases for easy data handling along with the useful drivers to serve data in most modern programs. Now how can i mark you as the answer?

Comment: I've just posted an answer that summarizes the comments. I'll clean up the comments so they're not clutter, now that an answer has been written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a third-party driver that supports the Clipper .NTX format.

[Advantage Database Server from Sybase](http://www.sybase.com/products/databasemanagement/advantagedatabaseserver/) has .Net data provider, ADO and ODBC drivers that will work, and their local server is free (at least at the time I'm writing this post). The latest versions can be [found here](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/content.aspx?key=20&Release=19). (I'm not affiliated with them in any way; I've just done some porting of old Clipper data.)

The documentation (available both from the downloaded installations and online) contain the entire contents of a commercially published [book](https://smile.amazon.com/Advantage-Database-Server-Developers-Guide/dp/1453769978/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1473215818&sr=1-1&keywords=advantage%20database%20server) that contains tutorials and reference materials that will help you get started.

There is a tag for Advantage here, so if you have questions regarding use you can post them using that tag. (Their Data Architect, available from the same site, will let you work with the data and indexes from an IDE as well.)